# splitting data from one excel sheet into multiple excel files using MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a large excel file which needs to be split into 10 equal parts based on the total number of entries.

For example if there are 1000 rows (with multiple columns), I need to read the entire worksheet and create them into 10 smaller worksheets (in the same workbook)

eg: rows 1-100: worksheet1, rows 101-200: worksheet2 and so on till worksheet 10.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `csvread()` and `csvwrite` in the form:

```
function split_file(filename_in)
    data = csvread(filename_in);
    data_size = size(data);
    tenthofdata = round(data_size(1)/10);
    for i = 1:9    %first nine
        csvwrite([filename_in num2str(i+1)],data(1:tenthofdata));
        data = data(tenthofdata+1:end);
    end
    csvwrite([filename_in '10'],data);    %remainder
end
```

Comment: If your file is not already in csv format, excel can save it as csv, or you can `strrep()`.